# I having problem to update sudo apt update on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, 22.04

Hello can anyone help me I am having problem in running sudo apt update in the 22.04. No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                            
Ign:5 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                               
Hit:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                                                                                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Ign:9 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Hit:6 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                                                       
Ign:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                                         
Ign:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                               
Ign:13 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:14 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                                                                 
Err:15 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release                                                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Err:16 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release                                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Err:18 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Err:20 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::25 80]
Hit:19 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease     
Hit:21 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease      
Reading package lists... Done                                    
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

After running this, Hello I had follow this sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list Copy/paste all the text from the newly generated sources.list to this file. Save it and close Gedit. Now, update apt. sudo apt-get update Now I getting this in my terminal,

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Hit:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                                                 
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:6 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                   
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/5.0 Release                                                                                                      
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                                                         
Hit:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                      
Hit:13 https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                   
Ign:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                    
Err:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::18 80]
Hit:17 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Now this I have when i run sudo nano etc/apt/sources/list

```
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu jammy partner
```

Comment: If you're using 22.04 (*jammy*) then why are there references to 21.10 (*impish*).  Also *jammy* or 22.04 is *supported* thus the references to old-releases.ubuntu.com are incorrect; that should be reverted & *impish* references removed (they can provide nothing useful for a 22.04 or *jammy* system except potentially add security holes via *unpatched* packages)

Comment: Still having the issue that did not work

Comment: I had run `cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak` and this `sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` and then run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade and this happen

Comment: Any lines that have the *jammy* release in (eg. `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy` need to be changed to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/`, as well as all lines that contain the *impish* release need to either be removed, or disabled (ie. commented out with a "#" at the start of the line)

Comment: But how can i change  (eg. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy need to be changed to http://archive.ubuntu.com/

Comment: You've not said if you're using a desktop or server system, but you can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu for more details.  I'd just use an editor (`vim` or `vi`) if it was me, but a GUI tool can be used too if using a desktop system.

Comment: Is it ok in this problem if i run reboot

Comment: I am using desktop system

Comment: Hello I had follow this sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
Copy/paste all the text from the newly generated sources.list to this file. Save it and close Gedit.

Now, update apt.

sudo apt-get update

Comment: I had updated by editing my question and all old comments are deleted

Comment: So you have a sources file somewhere (probably inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`) that includes the line `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security`. Find it and remove it!

Comment: I had run nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d but there is empty

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` is a directory and not a file...  The primary sources are found in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but other files can be added by users on the system inside the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which is empty on a clean install

Comment: So how i gonna remove this line http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security as /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ is empty

Comment: It's a directory and not a file...   If you use an editor that can handle directories, you'll the files contained within it; I gather `nano` you're using cannot do this (*sorry I don't use it*)... As that directory is empty on a new install; any files & thus names of files within it will have been given by users of your system who have `sudo` permissions... so you'll have to ask those users, or look what's in there yourself (*or ask an administrator of that system to look*)